# How to make paragraph structure like this photo [using only html and inline css]!

Tags: html, css, web, frontend

**Please help me with this paragraph I need to make my website paragraph to look like the photo below>>**
[I need this paragraph structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaF2V.png)

Comment: Show the code that you tried so far.

Comment: Can you please add some html and css you tried? It's hard to help you when we don't know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Here is the code I'm working with > Thank you for helping!
<p style="margin-left:80px;">1.2.1 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  class="row" style="font-weight:bold;display:inline-flex">
    <div>
        <p>1.2.1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>text text text ext text text text text text ext
        text text text text text ext text text text text text ext</p>
        <p>text text text text text ext
        text text text text text ext text text text text text ext text text text ext </p>
        <p>text text text text text ext
        text text text text text ext</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to display the paragraph as you want :

```
<p style="display:inline-block;width:7%;vertical-align:top;">1.2.1</p>
<p style="display:inline-block;width:90%;">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
```